# Can't view output from pointcloud_to_laserscan in RViz

Tags: ros2, rviz, pointcloud-to-laserscan

I am using `pointcloud_to_laserscan` in Foxy to convert `PointCloud2` to `LaserScan`, the output topic `/laser_scan`, `frame_id` and other info can be displayed in the terminal as shown below:

```
$ ros2 topic echo/laser_scan
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1698975210
    nanosec: 149751663
  frame_id: laser_link
angle_min: -1.5707999467849731
angle_max: 1.5707999467849731
angle_increment: 0.008700000122189522
time_increment: 0.0
scan_time: 0.33329999446868896
range_min: 0.44999998807907104
range_max: 50.0
ranges:
- 13.291234970092773
- 13.255324363708496
- 13.199461936950684
- 3.194882869720459
- 3.1873762607574463
- 3.178156614303589
- 3.1770803928375244
- 3.1462819576263428
- 3.1555559635162354
- 3.161247968673706
- 3.1447269916534424
- 3.1555066108703613
- 3.1548285484313965
- 3.1214966773986816
- 12.519904136657715
- 3.1467623710632324
- 3.137425422668457
- 3.1224148273468018
- 3.1295037269592285
- 3.1290066242218018
- 3.1189768314361572
- 3.165048599243164
- 3.1323049068450928
- 3.1336119174957275
- 3.1227383613586426
- 3.136373996734619
- 3.1675100326538086
- 3.1174399852752686
- 3.126782178878784
- 12.281723976135254
- 3.128790855407715
- 3.1251370906829834
- 3.138286828994751
- 3.142401695251465
- 3.1453566551208496
- 3.142239570617676
- 3.1454169750213623
- 12.181970596313477
- 3.1712160110473633
- 3.1680490970611572
- 3.1588122844696045
- 3.275080919265747
- 3.2058258056640625
- 3.200042486190796
- 3.1886119842529297
- 3.2230935096740723
- 3.2907326221466064
- 3.2369861602783203
- 3.2296266555786133
- 3.2320189476013184
- 3.257861614227295
- 3.2472219467163086
- 3.277601718902588
- 3.261584520339966
- 3.345512866973877
- 3.349425792694092
- 3.3572516441345215
- 3.3204658031463623
- 3.31103515625
- 3.3463590145111084
- 3.392467737197876
- 3.3674280643463135
- 3.365715980529785
- 3.4002931118011475
- 3.3937184810638428
- 11.614766120910645
- 3.4184677600860596
- 3.436464309692383
- 11.661864280700684
- 11.714645385742188
- 11.694036483764648
- 3.4993364810943604
- 3.5222747325897217
- 3.5290210247039795
- 9.70873737335205
- 7.407835483551025
- 3.58827543258667
- 3.632357358932495
- 3.6222918033599854
- 3.634817361831665
- 3.6534430980682373
- 3.6565439701080322
- 0.5653306841850281
- 3.729703426361084
- 0.5622578263282776
- 3.729703426361084
- 3.7218265533447266
- 3.7375805377960205
- 11.377861022949219
- 11.4055814743042
- 11.45706558227539
- 11.492709159851074
- 11.550622940063477
- 11.571914672851562
- 11.61536693572998
- 11.670920372009277
- 11.730324745178223
- 11.76596736907959
- 11.821412086486816
- 11.872894287109375
- 11.999622344970703
- 12.030619621276855
- 12.053903579711914
- 12.084951400756836
- 12.162569046020508
- 12.193614959716797
- 12.29063606262207
- 12.329442977905273
- 12.364372253417969
- 12.3721342086792
- 12.368252754211426
- 12.368252754211426
- 12.3721342086792
- 12.379895210266113
- 12.383776664733887
- 12.395419120788574
- 12.410942077636719
- 12.441988945007324
- 12.523487091064453
- 12.589461326599121
- 12.686481475830078
- 12.752455711364746
- 12.849478721618652
- 12.915452003479004
- 13.024114608764648
- 13.09785270690918
- 13.202634811401367
- 13.264728546142578
- '...'
intensities: []
---
```

but open RViz, modify the ID and add /laser_scan topic, nothing is displayed. The relevant parameters used are as follows：

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='pointcloud_to_laserscan', executable='pointcloud_to_laserscan_node',
            remappings=[('cloud_in', '/fusion_points'),
                        ('scan',  '/laser_scan')],
            parameters=[{
                'target_frame': 'laser_link',
                'transform_tolerance': 0.1,
                'min_height': -1.0,
                'max_height': 5.0,
                'angle_min': -1.5708,  # -M_PI/2
                'angle_max': 1.5708,  # M_PI/2
                'angle_increment': 0.0087,  # M_PI/360.0
                'scan_time': 0.3333,
                'range_min': 0.45,
                'range_max': 50.0,
                'use_inf': True,
                'inf_epsilon': 1.0
            }],
            name='pointcloud_to_laserscan'
        )
    ])
```

Does anyone know how to fix it？ Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! In the following statement, _open RViz, modify the ID and add /laser_scan topic_ what do you mean by "modify the ID"? I suggest adding the visualization by clicking on "By topic" tab inside RViz, where you can see your topic available. Next, please set the "Fixed Frame" to "laser_link" inside "Global Options" in RViz.